# Why I can't buy books from Kindle Store using Kindle app on iPad?

Tags: amazon, kindle-app, ios

It's really surprising to me to see why it is not easy to buy a book using the Kindle reader app on iPad. It has only provision to download the samples but there is no option to buy a complete book. For that I am using a browser or Amazon Store app. Is there anything I am missing here or it's just like that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because otherwise Amazon would have to give Apple a cut of the 'in-app purchases'.

[One article on the subject.](http://www.theverge.com/2013/7/30/4572170/amazon-finds-clever-way-around-apple-restrictions-with-kindle-ios-app)

Comment: That makes sense.